# Starting puma w/o `bundle exec` works; doesn't work with bundle exec; BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG env var not available during RUBYOPT="-rbundler/setup" run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundler, puma

I have created a docker container with a Rails 5.2 app. The Dockerfile is here: https://pastebin.com/T1hjYtJ8 . The compose file is here: https://pastebin.com/VEJBT8ZK . They may not be strictly relevant to this question, but still I am giving links to the configs, just in case. It is a pretty standard Dockerfile and compose file.

The `puma.rb` used in the app is shown here: https://pastebin.com/ic9ig3bC .

When I create the container, puma is executed as `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`. The puma process throws errors in the `puma_error.log` file:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find public_suffix-3.0.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `specs'
    ...
```

It is saying that it cannot find some gem. That gem happens to be a development gem. But I am starting the puma process with my environment set to `staging`. All the required environment variables are set correctly. The output of `env` in the container is shown below:

```
RUBYGEMS_VERSION=2.7.7
BUNDLER_VERSION=1.16.3
PUMA_THREADS_MAX=8
EXECJS_RUNTIME=Disabled
HOSTNAME=8d968df601db
RUBY_VERSION=2.5.1
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
PUMA_THREADS_MIN=2
RAILS_ROOT=/myapp
PWD=/myapp
HOME=/home/deploy
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
BUNDLE_PATH=/usr/local/bundle
BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
RAILS_ENV=staging
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true
TERM=xterm
BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1
RUBY_MAJOR=2.5
SHLVL=1
PUMA_NUM_WORKERS=2
PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bundle/gems/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

So, I do not understand why bundler setup is trying to load the development gems.

If I run the puma process without the "bundle exec", like so: `puma -C config/puma.rb`, then the app works! Comparing the differences between having and not having the "bundle exec", I noticed that the problem was the `RUBYOPT="-rbundler/setup"` environment variable, which gets set by `bundle exec`.

For some reason, the bundler setup process is not reading my environment and loads the development environments gems by default. How do I figure out why this is happening and how do I solve this?

**UPDATE**

After more debugging, I have narrowed down the problem to this: there is a `BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG` environment variable set to `/usr/local/bundle/` by the base Ruby docker image. All my gems are also installed to this folder. The bundler config is also in this folder (this config file has the all-important `--without` / `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:test"` setting). Bundler is supposed to read this environment variable to find the config file. But this environment variable is not available when `bundler/setup` is running! So, bundler ends up using a default config, which loads gems from all groups.

To investigate this, I added the following line in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/setup.rb`:

`puts "++++++++++ In setup.rb = All ENV variables: #{ENV.to_h}."`

The output is below:

```
{"RUBYGEMS_VERSION"=>"2.7.7",
 "BUNDLER_VERSION"=>"1.16.3",
 "PUMA_THREADS_MAX"=>"8",
 "EXECJS_RUNTIME"=>"Disabled",
 "HOSTNAME"=>"8d968df601db",
 "RUBY_VERSION"=>"2.5.1",
 "GEM_HOME"=>"/usr/local/bundle",
 "PUMA_THREADS_MIN"=>"2",
 "RAILS_ROOT"=>"/myapp",
 "PWD"=>"/myapp",
 "HOME"=>"/home/deploy",
 "RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"=>"true",
 "RAILS_ENV"=>"staging",
 "RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"=>"true",
 "TERM"=>"xterm",
 "RUBY_MAJOR"=>"2.5",
 "RUBYLIB"=>"",
 "SHLVL"=>"1",
 "PUMA_NUM_WORKERS"=>"2",
 "PATH"=>"/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bundle/gems/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
 "_"=>"/usr/local/bin/bundle",
 "PUMA_BUNDLER_PRUNED"=>"1",
 "RACK_ENV"=>"staging",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLE_BIN_PATH"=>"BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLE_GEMFILE"=>"BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLER_ORIG_MANPATH"=>"BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLER_VERSION"=>"1.16.3",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_HOME"=>"/usr/local/bundle",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_MANPATH"=>"BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_PATH"=>"/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bundle/gems/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_RB_USER_INSTALL"=>"BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL",
 "BUNDLER_ORIG_RUBYOPT"=>"BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL",
 "GEM_PATH"=>""}
```

You will notice that the `BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG` environment variable is missing from this list. You will notice that this ENV var IS available in the shell (output of `env`). It is also available if I run `bundle exec env`.

Why is this environment variable being removed during the `bundler/setup` run? I am assuming that this removal is being done by bundler, but I may be wrong. I am not able to find where it is being removed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: is the `puma` gem listed in your gemfile? Remember that `bundle exec` limits you to gems that are listed in the gemfile.

Comment: Yes, the puma gem is listed. After receiving no answers on SO, I posted the same question in [bundler's github issues](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6667). The issue turned out to be with Puma gem's code. More details in the issue.